# "As becomes obvious" or "As it becomes obvious"?

Tags: pronouns, dummy-it, extraposition

An essay of mine has been corrected so that my original sentence:

> As it becomes obvious, going to the market has not been my favorite thing to do.

becomes:

> As becomes obvious, going to the market has not been my favorite thing to do.

I must admit that the first sentence (my original) sounds much better to my own ears. A quick Google search returns 400k results for my version, 35k for the corrected one.

Whom do I believe, my gut instinct and Google (feel free to laugh) or a professor of English (a native speaker)?

Comment: They're both fine. In an opening aside remark like this, one can extrapose or not, and since the focused material is already at the end and doesn't have to be moved, extraposition simply inserts dummy _it_.

Comment: This is going to be easier to answer knowing the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Apologies for not including the rest of the sentence - I didn't realize it was important. I've edited it now

Answer (score -2):

I believe they are both correct, depending on the rest of the sentence. For the first example I would say:

> As **it** becomes obvious, going to the market, I was being stalked by a gang of thugs.

For the second example I would say:

> As becomes obvious, going to the market is something I have little patience for.

*It* represents a specific situation in the first example. In the second example there is just an open feeling of something you don’t wish to do, so there is no need to specify that part with the use of *it*.

Comment: What does the 'it' refer to in the first example.